# Searching for npm packages via Node

Tags: node.js, heroku, coffeescript, npm

Here's how I search for Npm packages, but it causes Heroku to either time out or go over memory limit, so I'm hoping someone know of a smarter solution.

```
npm = require 'npm'

packageCache = null

module.exports = class Npm
  @search: (searchTerms, callback) ->
    if packageCache?
      return callback null, packageCache
    npm.load ->
      npm.commands.search searchTerms, true, (err, results) ->
        return callback err if err?
        packageCache = results
        callback null, results
```

It bewilders me why npmjs.org doesn't have an API.

Comment: on heroku, there is a 30 second timeout for web requests to dynos. if you want to do a long running task like this, you need to create a background job. There are concrete examples for every heroku platform and a discussion of the process here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing

Comment: yes, but I would still run out of memory.

Comment: ah, I see. There was a Javascript Jabber episode a month ago talking about the improvements in npm 2.0. I don't recall an API being on the horizon, but hey, it is open source, I'm sure they'd love some one to build it. :)

Comment: it seems something is brewing in the community. I don't see why everyone needs to download all packages.

Answer (score 0):

I created a npm package that can cache the results for me (https://github.com/webjay/npm-search-store), although I still have issues with memory, which seems to be a know [issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3867).